# Multiple assignments in groovy

Tags: groovy

In groovy I can do:

```
def (zip111, zip222, zip333) = ["111", "222", "333"];
```

But I can't do:

```
String (zip111, zip222, zip333) = ["111", "222", "333"];
```

Is there anyway I can multiply assign Strings?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do:

```
def (String zip111, String zip222, String zip333) = ["111", "222", "333"]
```

Or, pre-define your vars:

```
String zip111, zip222, zip333
(zip111, zip222, zip333) = ["111", 3, "333"]
```